# Why is this Makefile behavior different from bash

Tags: bash, makefile, environment-variables

So I have a make file with various commands. One of the commands just runs the main python script, but before doing so it exports environment variables stored in `dev.env`.

The make file command to run the main python script is:

```
run-dev:
    # Why does this need to be one line to work???  
    set -a && source dev.env && set +a && python __main__.py
```

This runs just fine, both as a make command (`make run-dev`) and in bash (`set -a && source dev.env && set +a && python __main__.py`. All the environment variables are exported to the environment before the `__main__.py` file invocation, which loads those environment variables using `os.environ`.

But why does the following not work in a make file?

```
run-dev:
    set -a
    source dev.env
    set +a
    # Python's environment cannot see the variables from `dev.env` in `os.environ` 
    python __main__.py
```

Here, `make run-dev` fails because `__main__.py` can't see the environment variables? Copy-pasting those 4 lines to bash still works. Why?

Comment: I should point out that this makefile is not portable, as-is.  make doesn't run bash to execute recipes, it runs `/bin/sh`.  On some systems, such as Red Hat-like systems, `/bin/sh` is the same as bash.  On other systems, such as Debian-derived systems, `/bin/sh` is a standard POSIX shell like dash which doesn't implement extra bash features.  Your makefile won't work on systems like that becacuse it uses the bash-specific `source`.  You can either fix it to use the POSIX-standard `.` or add an explicit `SHELL := /bin/bash` to your makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, each line in a recipe is run in it's only shell, you need ONESHELL:

```
.ONESHELL:

run-dev:
    set -a
    source dev.env
    set +a
    # Python's environment cannot see the variables from `dev.env` in `os.environ` 
    python __main__.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
bash -c 'a=1; echo a=$a'
```

and

```
bash -c 'a=1'
bash -c 'echo a=$a'
```

Your two Makefile rules are being run a bit like that.

[Makefile Execution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_13_03):

> An execution line is built from the command line by removing any prefix characters. Except as described under the at-sign prefix, the execution line shall be written to the standard output, optionally preceded by a . The execution line shall then be executed by a shell as if it were passed as the argument to the system() interface, except that if errors are not being ignored then the shell -e option shall also be in effect. If errors are being ignored for the command (as a result of the -i option, a '-' command prefix, or a .IGNORE special target), the shell -e option shall not be in effect. The environment for the command being executed shall contain all of the variables in the environment of make.

[system()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html):

> The system() function shall behave as if a child process were created using fork(), and the child process invoked the sh utility using execl()

---

As @Philippe points out, some versions of make allow this behaviour to be overridden by adding a [`.ONESHELL`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_18) target:

> The default in some advanced versions of make is to group all the command lines for a target and execute them using a single shell invocation; the System V method is to pass each line individually to a separate shell. The single-shell method has the advantages in performance and the lack of a requirement for many continued lines. However, converting to this newer method has caused portability problems with many historical makefiles, so the behavior with the POSIX makefile is specified to be the same as that of System V. It is suggested that the special target .ONESHELL be used as an implementation extension to achieve the single-shell grouping for a target or group of targets.